# Pandas: KeyError when trying to merge two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Excel sheets (Master & Input) with the same index column but a different number of columns (see below). I want to merge the Input DF into the Master DF **if new rows have been added** (see ID 103-105) OR **an item in the Input DF has been updated** (see ID 102). Other columns can be ignored.

Dataframe 1 (Master):

[image: Master DF]

Dataframe 2 (Input):

[image: Input DF]

Goal (updated cells marked in yellow):

[image]

I am using the following script:

```
inputDf = pd.read_excel(inputFileName).set_index("ID")
masterDf = pd.read_excel(masterFileName).set_index("ID")

# Update existing rows
masterDf.update(inputDf)

# find out which ids are new
ids_of_new_rows = set(inputDf.index) - set(masterDf.index)

# get new rows that should be added to master
rows_to_add = masterDf.loc[ids_of_new_rows, inputDf.columns & masterDf.columns]
```

I am able to update the Master DF and get `ids_of_new_rows`. Output:
`{'CR103', 'CR104', 'CR105'}`

However, when trying to get `rows_to_add`, I always receive the following error:

```
KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['CR103', 'CR104', 'CR105'], dtype='object', name='ID')] are in the [index]"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it should be rows_to_add = inputDf.loc etc etc, but you are pointing to masterDf there. This is where the mistake is.

Comment: Thank you, @SandervandenOord. What a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

#### About the error

The error comes from the fact that there are not rows with `ID` of `['CR103', 'CR104', 'CR105']` in the `masterDf`, but in the `inputDf`. What you are trying to do is probably

```py
rows_to_add = inputDf.loc[ids_of_new_rows, inputDf.columns & masterDf.columns]
```

### What you probably want to do

```py
inputDf = pd.read_excel(inputFileName).set_index("ID")
masterDf = pd.read_excel(masterFileName).set_index("ID")

# Update existing rows
masterDf.update(inputDf)
# Add new rows
masterDf = pd.concat((masterDf, inputDf.loc[inputDf.index.difference(masterDf.index), inputDf.columns & masterDf.columns]))
```

Here the [Index.difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) is used to get the index values in `inputDf` that are not present in `masterDf`.

Comment: Thank you. Using your solution, additional columns from Input DF are getting added to the Master DF as well. Those should be ignored. Hence, the correct solution is to use the corrected `rows_to_add` in the concat statement, like this: `df_result = pd.concat([masterDf, rows_to_add])`

Comment: Oh yeah missed that you'd like to drop the extra columns from `inputDf`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct script to achieve the outcome described below. Simple solution was to change inputDF and masterDF...

```
# Define DataFrame
inputDf = pd.read_excel(inputFileName).set_index("ID")
masterDf = pd.read_excel(masterFileName).set_index("ID")

# Update existing rows
masterDf.update(inputDf)

# find out which ids are new
ids_of_new_rows = set(inputDf.index) - set(masterDf.index)

# get new rows that should be added to master
rows_to_add = inputDf.loc[ids_of_new_rows, inputDf.columns & masterDf.columns]

# add new rows to existing master
df_result = pd.concat([masterDf, rows_to_add])
```